# Ajax/jQuery pass variable data to another jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two jQuery calls, one to get visitor city by IP, another which opens a pop-up on a website. I have a problem, first call get the client city but I can not, not sure how to pass it to the second query. Does anyone know how to do it?

client_city needs to be passed to this query, as city=client_city

```
hidden: 'utm_source,utm_medium,utm_campaign,utm_term,utm_content'
```

I tried various ways, but somewhy first call doesn't pass the variable data outside its function, any ideas?

```
// First Call to get City
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'https://ip-api.io/json?api_key=****',
  success: function(data) {
  client_city=data.city
  console.log(client_city)
  }
});
```

```
// Second Call to create pop
jQuery(function($){
    
    $('#menu-item-37 a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var popup = window.tf.createPopup('sxmSCYSc', {
            hideHeaders: true,
            transitiveSearchParams: ['utm_source', 'utm_medium', 'utm_campaign', 'utm_term', 'utm_content'],
            iframeProps: {
                title: 'Dermatologo konsultacija internetu - iDerma'
            },
            medium: 'snippet',
            hidden: 'utm_source,utm_medium,utm_campaign,utm_term,utm_content'
        });
        popup.toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just make a global variable for the data that you want to use in the other function.

Comment: Tried following sollution, but doesnt seem to make any effect, ajax call works, but doesn't change variable value.

Comment: i think the console log value that you get is undefined because the ajax is still running but you call the value already. you can try then function, to do things when the data is successfully fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it like this, but still no success.

```
var client_city = ''

jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'https://ip-api.io/json?api_key=****',
  success: function(data) {
  client_city = data.city

  
  }
});

console.log(client_city)
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your question with this information as this not a real answer.